# Comma separated list from a C# 4.0 List

Tags: c#

I have a List of people, and I need a way to make a comma separated list of the person.Email fields

Is there a quick way to do this using c# 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
string csv = string.Join(",", list.Select(p => p.Email).ToArray());
```

Comment: That'll work until you encounter an email address with a comma in it. Don't laugh. the syntax for email addresses allows for far more than just `mailbox@domain` style email addresses.

Comment: @Nicholas, that would be a violation of the RFC is there was a comma that wasn't quoted.  So if this is just a email address and not a compound address including display name then it won't be an issue.

Comment: This is a valid email address `John Smith (Acme, Inc.) <jsmith@acme.com>` per the RFCs. Ditto for `"Smith, John" <jsmith@acme.com>`. Double quotes are likely to break CSV parsers in the wrong places. Legal email addresses cover far more than just simple addresses like `mailbox@domain`.

Comment: @Nicholas why don't you suggest a better answer then?

Comment: Because parsing CSV-style data properly is far more difficult that it seems. You have to deal with (1) quoting issues, (2) what to do with leading/trailing whitespace in unquoted fields, (3) what to do with embedded line breaks in quoted field (e.g., in quoted fields, the MS Excel "standard" for CSV doesn't support escape sequences for anything other than an embedded double quote, etc. Then you have to deal with differences in implementation (e.g., some CSV producers use C-style escapes in quoted fields, or "quote" fields with characters other than double quote. Use a pre-written CSV parser.

Answer (score 3):

Using some delicious LINQ:

```
string csv = string.Join(",", people.Select(p => p.Email));
```

Comment: `string.Join(delimiter, string[])`, you have them backward.  And you need .ToArray() after your Select() because it expects an string[] not an Enumerable<T>.

Comment: @Chuck: not for a few minutes, refresh :P Also, C# 4.0 now accepts an `IEnumerable<string>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx)

Comment: Ah cool about the 4.0, I haven't started to use it as I don't have VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Using [LINQ to CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx) is extremely easy. Take a look at the link.

All you need to do is place some attributes in the `Person` class, and you will be able to both read/write from/to .csv easily :)

**Here's an example:**

```
var emails =
    from p in people
    select new { p.Email };

cc.Write(emails, @"C:\emails.csv", outputFileDescription)
```

where `outputFileDescription` is declared before (take a look at the examples).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "saurabh", LastName = "sharma" });

persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "sandeep", LastName = "singh" });

persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Ivan", LastName = "gupta" });                       

Response.Write(string.Join(",", (from p in persons select p.FirstName).ToArray()));
```

Comment: If any Person field in the list contains a `,`, that won't work.

Comment: this is a constraint no name contains ',' or email field ','. If it contains then it would join as per the value like  -  saurabh,sandee,p,Ivan. So the moral is your data is corrupt. So either go for simple approach if you know your constraints.otherwise while adding list you can remove (, etc) characters.